# Superscript placement sub/superscripts

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I noticed that with many nested sub/superscripts, LaTeX starts really messing with the script placements.
For example I need to typeset math like
`\varphi_e^{A_{s(x)}, 1}` or even `\mathcal{W}_{\varphi_e^{A_{s(x)}, 1}(y)}`.
In both cases the `A` is typeset very high relative to the `\varphi`. It is entirely above the `\varphi`.
I think the expression `A_{s(x)}, 1` becomes too disconnected from the `\varphi`, impeding readability.
Also, in the second expression, the `\varphi` is typeset every far from the `\mathcal{W}`.

[image: \varphi_e^{A_{s(x)}, 1}]
[image: \mathcal{W}_{\varphi_e^{A_{s(x)}, 1}(y)}]

Is there a way to typeset the `A` more like it is normally typeset (without a subscript, like in `\varphi_e^A`)?

[image: \varphi_e^A]

I would (of course) prefer to have a somewhat automatic solution, i.e. not having to fiddle with `\fontdimenXX` parameters **every time** I need to typeset an equation involving nested sub- and superscripts.

PS: I am using `LuaLaTeX` with `unicode-math` and the (default) latin modern math font.

Comment: The default spacing is entirely determined by the constants in the math table for the font you are using. You haven't said what that is, a test file that shows the font setup and allows people to test answers is always useful in any question.

Comment: note that tex is positioning vertical boxes the bottom of the (x) only just clears the top of the e and tex doesn't know they won't over-print. you cound hide the extent  of the terms with `\smash{...}`

Comment: I'm just using latin modern math. Added that to the question. Tried `\smash{e}` as the subscript and that indeed significantly improves the typesetting! Still, the $\mathcal{W}$ is quite distant from it's subscript, both horizontal and vertical. Thank you for very fast the comments!

Comment: it would have been better to provide a test document (as in egreg's answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the particular case, where the superscript's descender will not clash with the subscript, you can `\smash` the bottom of the superscript.

But you should consider alternative and easier to read notation, in my opinion.

```
documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{W}_{\varphi_{e}^{\smash[b]{A_{s(x)},1}}(y)}
\]

\[
\mathcal{W}\bigl(\varphi_{e}^{A_{s(x)},1}(y)\bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the notation is a bit unfortunate, but it is not always possible to deviate from long-standing conventions in mathematics...

Comment: @beehive I know, of course. On the other hand a four-story formula is really hard to read.