# Lowering the superscript

Tags: math-mode, equations, subscripts, superscripts

Is it possible to lower the superscript in

[image]

to achieve something like this?

[image]

Comment: Possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592266/superscript-placement-sub-superscripts is also relevant, i.e., the use of `\smash`.

Comment: @Marjin Thanks! ``\smash`` is the answer.

Comment: I'd set the font parameters if I was not happy with them. In luatex one can also force the sub/superscript into certain positions.